# New to Bootstrap -- need to figure out layout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand that Bootstrap is a grid-based system. What I want to do is create a category page (catgegory of products) that can have as many DIVs as the screen will allow. Basically it is "reverse responsive" in that the number of DIVs grows as the screen grows larger.

Right now I seem to be "stuck" using a set number of DIVs based upon the grid-system of Bootstrap. Perhaps I should not be using the Bootstrap layout features for this? If not, how can I accomplish what I am looking to do?

Example:

If on one screen I get this:

```
<div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content2</div>
   <div>content3</div>
   <div>content4</div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>content5</div>
   <div>content6</div>
   <div>content7</div>
   <div>content8</div>
</div>
```

When viewed on a larger screen it should be like this:

```
<div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content2</div>
   <div>content3</div>
   <div>content4</div>
   <div>content5</div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>content6</div>
   <div>content7</div>
   <div>content8</div>
</div>
```

and on an even larger screen it should be:

```
<div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content2</div>
   <div>content3</div>
   <div>content4</div>
   <div>content5</div>
   <div>content6</div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>content7</div>
   <div>content8</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way (any way at all) to accomplish this?

Thanks!

UPDATE: For those needing to visualize, this is an image of my layout with just 4 columns, but if the screen was larger I would want it to grow to 5, 6, 7 or even 8 columns:

[image]

Comment: Use grids, that should help you

Comment: What version of boostrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap isn't going to change your HTML markup for you.  I'm having a hard time visualizing what you want it to look like, is there a picture or something you can draw?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3. As for a picture, just imagine that it is a row of images. Depending upon how large the screen is there are more or less images displayed.

Comment: There is an example for BS3 on [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). Just search for "Stacked-to-horizontal".

Comment: I added an image to my original post showing what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* (maybe) what you are looking for here is what bootstrap (2, at least) does by default - 12 columns that wrap as necessary depending on the page size. What you want to do is use a class on your div's to set the number of columns that div will take up. Pretty much, what you are looking at is this:

```
<div class="span2">First Column</div>
<div class="span2">Second Column</div>
<div class="span2">Third Column</div>
<div class="span2">Fourth Column</div>
<div class="span2">Fifth Column</div>
<div class="span2">Sixth Column</div>
```

Then just let bootstrap do its magic. Try resizing your window and it should float the columns correctly based on the size of your window (in other words, it should be responsive). If you want to make a column bigger, just change the number in the span (up) and be sure to remove that same amount from other spans. Hope that helps!

NOTE: For bootstrap3, the syntax is different (see ".col-md-*" on [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration))

Comment: Good answer; I didn't even realize this is what he was trying to do from the question until I read your answer.

Comment: So if I just wrap all the col-md-3 class DIVs under one row DIV they will just automatically flow the way I am looking for? Won't they be limited by the col-md-# that I am using (3 being 25% so 4 to a row)?

Comment: What you want to do here is start with the col-md-# that closest matches your images. Then as you shrink the page, you can specify a "min-width" on any of those div's and the page will automatically wrap when the width would be too small. The only other thing to do, then is possibly switch the number of columns based on how thing scale. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for your patience and your detailed answer. I believe I made it work using your tips. Bootstrap is fun.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. Glad I could help!